# What VOIP servers for Ubuntu can I find that have very low latency

Tags: 11.04, server, voip

I have used Mumble and Teamspeak in the Ubuntu Server. Mumble is suppose very low latency but the client is horrible. At least compared to Teamspeak. the memory usage was good. The configuration and installation was a little complicated.

For teamspeak the low latency is not as better as mumble but the client is very good.

What other Low Latency VOIP server for Ubuntu exist and how is the look and feel for their client and the quality for their server.

Comment: I'm confused by your question. Latency and lag are determined by distance to server, not by the software. I run 6 TS servers off of a box I own on Ubuntu and it all operates smoothly and efficiently (the total memory and CPU usage of the 6 server instances alongside each other is <=387MB RAM and 10% of one CPU core at max).  From 8 different locations including across the world (the TS servers are meeting places for global groups), latency/lag is never > 80ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you best choice for low latency VOIP is Mumble, and that the way to go through this is to familiarise better with how the client works or gets configured.

The initial setup of Mumble has several steps, which are required in order to get the best results. There are always ways to improve the wizard, so you can suggest enhancements.

You may have some suggestions on how the UI of the client can be improved; this being free and open-source software, you can contribute your suggestions. It is possible to rearrange the UI so that it becomes more user-friendly for you. It requires little programming experience and it is a rewarding process.